# Perl YAML::Tiny get hash of hash to variable

Tags: perl, hash, yaml

I have a yaml object

```
$VAR1 = bless( [
             {
               'Cluster2' => {
                               'source_mount' => '/mnt/uploads',
                               'destination_mount' => '/var/pub',
                               'default' => 'no',
                               'dir' => '/a /d /e'
                             },
               'Cluster1' => {
                               'source_mount' => '/mnt/uploads',
                               'destination_mount' => '/var/pub',
                               'default' => 'yes',
                               'dir' => '/b /c'
                             }
             }
           ], 'YAML::Tiny' );
```

I was specifically looking to get the value for the key dir under Cluster1.
I take the Cluster1 from an environment variable like

```
my $cluster=$ENV{SHARD}; #returns Cluster1
```

and try to retrive the dir as

```
print values %{$yaml->[0]->{Cluster1}{'dir'}};
```

But it says

```
Can't use string ("/b /c") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use
```

If I try

```
print values %{$yaml->[0]->{Cluster1}};
```

It returns

```
/mnt/uploads/var/pubyes/b /c
```

What am I doing wring here?

Thanks.

Comment: I found a solution, but I am not sure if this is the best way.

    `my %host_conf = %{$yaml->[0]->{Cluster1}};`
and then

    `print $host_conf{dir};`

gave me what I wanted. Any good suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is explained [here](https://metacpan.org/pod/YAML%3a%3aTiny#___pod) .

`$yaml->[0]->{Cluster1}{dir};` is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

`$yaml->[0]->{Cluster1}{'dir'};` is a simple string, you can get the value just like that.

The error you are receiving simply says that perl can't convert a string into a hash - the `%{ ... }` wrapper transforms your variable from a hash reference into a hash, but you have a string there, not a hashref, thus the error